# Как убрать на второй план псевдоэлемент :after?

Tags: html, css, css3

У меня есть элемент и псевдо элемент к нему.

```
 .hexagon {
        width: 20vw;
        height: 20vw;
        margin-top: 4vw;
        margin-bottom: 4vw;
        border-radius: 1vw;
        border: none;
        position: relative;
        background-color: red;
        display: flex;
        z-index: 222;
        &:before{
          content: "";
          position: relative;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 22vw;
          height: 22vw;
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
          transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
          border: 0.2vw solid #232f62;
          background-color: #1c7430;
          z-index: -1;
        }
      }
```

Но псевдоэлемент перекрывает основной элемент. z-index не помогает. Есть ли возможность поставить псевдо элемент на второй план ?

Дополнение:
Когда всё заработало получлась такая фигура.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть подобный вопрос на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032856/is-it-possible-to-set-the-stacking-order-of-pseudo-elements-below-their-parent-e

Comment: абсолютом псевдо элементы расположите ....relative это относительное позиционирование

Comment: Да спасибо, помогло, единственный момент ещё. 
Если есть фоновое изображение, у него надо z-index выставлять в  1. Иначе если ставишь у псевдоэлемента z-index: -1 background его закрывать начинает.

Comment: Да, только когда у z-index отрицательное значение он убирает элемент автоматически за бекграунд. С положительным значением такого не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда задается `z-index` у родительского блока, то создается новый контекст наложения и псевдоэлемент его наследует, т.к. является его потомком, по этому ни какой `z-index` не изменит его положения относительно родителя.
Будет работать, если не задавать `z-index` родительскому блоку, а указать его только для псевдоэлемента.

```css
.hexagon {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  margin-top: 4vw;
  margin-bottom: 4vw;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.hexagon::before {
  content: "";
  width: 22vw;
  height: 22vw;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  border: 0.2vw solid #232f62;
  background-color: #1c7430;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это последнее что мне получилось сделать из css. Полигон с прозрачным центром. Сработает если используется однотонный фон.
 1.Ставится очень широкий padding и border-radius 50%
 2. Применяется clip-path и ставится прозрачным сам элемент.Полигон будет виден на padding -е
 3. В псевдоэлементе делается то же самое, меняются только размеры и цвет полигона ставится равный цвету фона. (Нужно что бы сделать ровные бордюры.
 4. Псевдоэлемент делается тоже прозрачным.

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.hexagon-00 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2.5vw solid #ffd400;
  background-color: transparent;
  clip-path: polygon(92.32051% 40%, 93.79385% 43.1596%, 94.69616% 46.52704%, 95% 50%, 94.69616% 53.47296%, 93.79385% 56.8404%, 92.32051% 60%, 79.82051% 81.65064%, 77.82089% 84.50639%, 75.35575% 86.97152%, 72.5% 88.97114%, 69.3404% 90.44449%, 65.97296% 91.34679%, 62.5% 91.65064%, 37.5% 91.65064%, 34.02704% 91.34679%, 30.6596% 90.44449%, 27.5% 88.97114%, 24.64425% 86.97152%, 22.17911% 84.50639%, 20.17949% 81.65064%, 7.67949% 60%, 6.20615% 56.8404%, 5.30384% 53.47296%, 5% 50%, 5.30384% 46.52704%, 6.20615% 43.1596%, 7.67949% 40%, 20.17949% 18.34936%, 22.17911% 15.49361%, 24.64425% 13.02848%, 27.5% 11.02886%, 30.6596% 9.55551%, 34.02704% 8.65321%, 37.5% 8.34936%, 62.5% 8.34936%, 65.97296% 8.65321%, 69.3404% 9.55551%, 72.5% 11.02886%, 75.35575% 13.02848%, 77.82089% 15.49361%, 79.82051% 18.34936%);
}

.hexagon-00:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.3vw;
  left: -2.3vw;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2.3vw solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.97, 0.97);
  clip-path: polygon(92.32051% 40%, 93.79385% 43.1596%, 94.69616% 46.52704%, 95% 50%, 94.69616% 53.47296%, 93.79385% 56.8404%, 92.32051% 60%, 79.82051% 81.65064%, 77.82089% 84.50639%, 75.35575% 86.97152%, 72.5% 88.97114%, 69.3404% 90.44449%, 65.97296% 91.34679%, 62.5% 91.65064%, 37.5% 91.65064%, 34.02704% 91.34679%, 30.6596% 90.44449%, 27.5% 88.97114%, 24.64425% 86.97152%, 22.17911% 84.50639%, 20.17949% 81.65064%, 7.67949% 60%, 6.20615% 56.8404%, 5.30384% 53.47296%, 5% 50%, 5.30384% 46.52704%, 6.20615% 43.1596%, 7.67949% 40%, 20.17949% 18.34936%, 22.17911% 15.49361%, 24.64425% 13.02848%, 27.5% 11.02886%, 30.6596% 9.55551%, 34.02704% 8.65321%, 37.5% 8.34936%, 62.5% 8.34936%, 65.97296% 8.65321%, 69.3404% 9.55551%, 72.5% 11.02886%, 75.35575% 13.02848%, 77.82089% 15.49361%, 79.82051% 18.34936%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon-00"> </div>
```